# How to change a lower case to upper case using function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a input parameter to capital case.

```
text = input("write anything you wish you change to capital case:  ")

def case_change():
    text.upper()
    
print(case_change(text))
```

Comment: It seems you have the basic outline of the code already.. what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: As a _A result-oriented Analytics professional with 10 years of experience. Master in Python, PY- Spark, Pandas, SQL Database, Amazon S3, Knime, Tableau, Power BI, Google data Studio, Advance Excel, Macro, SAP, Tally ERP 9. Having the ability to work with the minimum of supervision.

An astute professional, expert in Business Analytics, more stuff_ ... should you be able to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not asking for an argument in the function `case_change`, but passing in `text` as an argument to it while calling `case_change`

Try:

```
text = input("write anything you wish you change to capital case: ")
def case_change(text):
   return text.upper()

upper_case = case_change(text)
print("capital case is: "+upper_case)
```